# Tick Format to Decimal Format Conversion

Tags: javascript

can anybody suggest me how can i convert a given Tick format number to decimal sing JavaScript ?

```
Tick Format                         Decimal
10-8           10+8/32              == 10.25
10-16/32       10+ 16/32            == 10.50
10-8+          10 + 8/32 + 1/64    == 10.265625
```

The format consists of an integer part, followed by '-' and then a fractional part specified in multiples of 1/32 (called a quote). There can be an optional '+' at the end to indicate a half-quote (1/64). As I am a beginner in JS it would be a great a help if anybody can suggest basic idea ( not full length code) to get started.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do this using RegExp:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/j5fL7zu7/)

```
// the tick format values
var array = ["10-8", "10-16/32", "10-8+"];
// regular expressions to check for the matches
var regexes = [/^\d+?-\d+?$/m, /^\d+?-\d+?\/\d+$/m, /^\d+?-\d+?\+$/m];
// this is where the decimal format values will go
var converted = [];

// loop through the array 'array'
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // for each string in array loop through the array 'regexes'
    for (r = 0; r < regexes.length; r++) {
        // Check if any regex matches
        if (regexes[r].exec(array[i])) {
            // get the first digit
            var x = parseInt(/^(\d+)-/m.exec(array[i])[1]);
            // get the second digit
            var y = parseInt(/-(\d+)\.*/m.exec(array[i])[1]);
            // if the regex is last add 1 / 64 else don't
            if (r == 2) {
                converted.push(x + (y / 32) + (1 / 64));
            } else {
                converted.push(x + (y / 32));
            }
        }
    }
}
// finally log the new array 'converted' which contains the decimal format to the console
console.log(converted)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
function decTick(str) {
    var toReturn = 0;
    var splitted = str.split('-');
    toReturn += splitted[0]*1;
    if (splitted.length>1) {
        if ( splitted[1].substring(splitted[1].length-1)=="+" ) {
            toReturn += 1/64;
            splitted[1] = splitted[1].replace('+','');
        };
        var fractional = splitted[1].split('/');
        toReturn += fractional[0]/32;
    };
    return toReturn;
};
console.log( decTick('10-8') );
console.log('-----------------------------');
console.log( decTick('10-16/32') );
console.log('-----------------------------');
console.log( decTick('10-8+') );
console.log('-----------------------------');
```

Output:

```
10.25
-----------------------------
10.5
-----------------------------
10.265625
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be shortest solution, converting to equation, than calculate with `eval()`:

```
function decTick(str) {
    return eval( str.replace(/\-([1-9]+)$/, '-$1/32').replace('+', '+1/64').replace('-', '+').replace(/\+(\d+)\+/, '+$1/32+') );
};
console.log( decTick('10-8') );
console.log('-----------------------------');
console.log( decTick('10-16/32') );
console.log('-----------------------------');
console.log( decTick('10-8+') );
console.log('-----------------------------');
console.log( decTick('10-16/32+') );
console.log('-----------------------------');
```

Outputs as expected:

```
10.25
-----------------------------
10.5
-----------------------------
10.265625
-----------------------------
10.515625
-----------------------------
```